# Search for a matching string between two dataframes, and assign the matching column's name to the other dataframe with a function (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, string-matching

"unique_receivers" is a Pandas dataframe with columns for unique transaction receivers, amounts and an empty column for categories which I want to fill with a function.

```
unique_receivers

    Receiver    Amount  Category
144 SALE        -18.93  
141 TACO BELL   -19.20  
78  MCDONALDS   -19.65  
104 EXPRESS     -20.00  
154 SHOP        -24.00
```

I want to fill the above dataframe's "Category" column based on its "Receiver" column's matches with search terms in another dataframe, "category_searchterms".

"category_searchterms" has categories as column names, and each category's column has its respective search terms.

Here's a sample of that dataframe:

```
categories

    Groceries   Electricity Fastfood
0   SHOP        ELCOMPANY   MCDONALDS
1   MARKET      POWER       SUBWAY
2   SALE                    PIZZA
```

**I want to go through every row of the "unique_receivers"'s "Receiver" column, look for a match in the "categories" dataframe, take the matching column's name and assign that to the first dataframe's "Category" column.**

I'm trying to do it with this function:

```
def add_category(searchterm):
    unique_receivers["Category"] = (category_searchterms == searchterm).any().idxmax()
```

And then call it:

```
unique_receivers.apply(add_category(unique_receivers["Receiver"]), axis=1)
```

**Problem:**

```
TypeError: ("'NoneType' object is not callable", 'occurred at index 144')
```

Index 144 is the first row in "unique_receivers". If I now call the dataframe, every row has been filled with the first category:

```
unique_receivers

    Receiver    Amount  Category
144 SALE        -18.93  Groceries   
141 TACO BELL   -19.20  Groceries   
78  MCDONALDS   -19.65  Groceries   
104 EXPRESS     -20.00  Groceries   
154 SHOP        -24.00  Groceries
```

How can I get the real matching category to appear on each row's "Category" column? Thank you.

Comment: What if the receivers' names have a space in them, i.e. two or more separate words? These methods only find the 1-word receivers?

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
import pandas as pd

unique_receivers['Category'] = unique_receivers['Receivers'].apply(lambda x: pd.np.resize(categories.columns.values[pd.np.where(categories.isin([x]))[1]],1)[0])
```

The `np.resize` is to ensure you don't get an `IndexError` if no values are found

Comment: Thank you, it does add the correct category to 2 out of over a 100 receivers but not the rest, I will try to understand why those 2 (they don't seem any different from the rest).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and a custom `lambda` function:

```
unique_receivers['Category'] = unique_receivers.Receiver.apply(lambda x:
                               ''.join([i for i in categories.columns 
                               if categories.loc[:,i].str.contains(x).any()]) 
                               or None)

 Receiver  Amount   Category
144       SALE  -18.93  Groceries
141   TACOBELL  -19.20       None
78   MCDONALDS  -19.65   Fastfood
104    EXPRESS  -20.00       None
154       SHOP  -24.00  Groceries
```

---

Or using [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) and right [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `df1`:

```
categories.melt(var_name='Category').merge(unique_receivers, 
                                           left_on='value', right_on='Receiver',
                                           how='right')\
                                           [['Receiver','Amount','Category']]

    Receiver  Amount   Category
0       SHOP  -24.00  Groceries
1       SALE  -18.93  Groceries
2  MCDONALDS  -19.65   Fastfood
3   TACOBELL  -19.20       None
4    EXPRESS  -20.00       None
```

Comment: Would you know why both of these methods can only find the matches for the receivers that consist of just one word, but not if the receiver's name is 2+ words? 

For example if there was TACO BELL as a receiver, these methods wouldn't find the category for it if the search term in categories was TACO.